# Webpages load really slow when boleean is true. How to speed things up?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a working code but my web pages load very slow when boolean is true. Any way to speed things up? Here is the code:

```
Private Property bool2 As Boolean
Private Sub WebBrowserCheck(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs)
    bool2 = True
    Dim token As String
    Dim pretoken As String
    pretoken = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString
    token = pretoken.Substring(27, 9)
    Dim tvshowcheck As String
    tvshowcheck = "https://www.imdb.com/title/" & token & "/episodes"
    Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest
    Dim res As System.Net.WebResponse
    req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(tvshowcheck)
    Try
        res = req.GetResponse()
    Catch nub As WebException
        bool2 = False
    End Try
    If bool2 = True Then
        TextBox2.Visible = True
        TextBox3.Visible = True
        TextBox4.Visible = True
        TextBox5.Visible = True
    Else
        TextBox2.Visible = False
        TextBox3.Visible = False
        TextBox4.Visible = False
        TextBox5.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub WebBrowserCheckHandler()
    AddHandler WebBrowser1.Navigated, New WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(AddressOf WebBrowserCheck)
End Sub
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigated(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated
    If WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        WebBrowserCheckHandler()
    End If
    End Sub
```

The part untill End Try runs very well.

Comment: Which boolean are you setting to true? What happens when it is false?

Comment: bool2 is set to true. When URL gives 404 Error bool2 is set to false. It seems that if that does not happen some loop is formed or whatever since my WebBrowser1 freezes (Textboxes are visible).

Comment: There is no other code running when navigating.

Comment: mb finally will fix it. Im not a programmer. Nope it did not.

Comment: CPU usage shows that webbrowsercheck is being executed.

Comment: Just needed to remove handler. I know nub questions are not expected but me not programmer :D

Comment: Question from new and inexperienced programmers are welcome here, but we expect people to do their research first and then if they still need to ask then to write a clear question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ .